# Split string into multidimensional NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Assuming the following example array:

```
{"/documents", "/documents/files", "/pictures"}
```

I wish to create a multidimensional NSMutableDictionary that looks like (if I were to create it manually):

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"documents", @"pictures", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionary] forKey:@"files"], [NSDictionary dictionary], nil];

NSMutableDictionary *demoDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

NSLog(@"%@", demoDict);
```

Which would log as:

```
documents = {
    files = {
    };
};
pictures = {
};
```

**How could I generate this automatically from a similar array with path lengths of an infinite length (so dictionaries of infinite dimensions?)**

What I have so far (hopefully it's useful as a starting point) is;
I put the comments of the logic above the code to make it easier on the eyes:
(_folderPaths is the array)

```
/**
 *set the root dictionary
 *iterate through the array
 *Split the path down by the separator
 *iterate over the path parts
 *make sure there is a part to the part, eliminates initial slash or
    double slashes
 *Check if key exists
 *if not then set a new mutdict for future children with key being the pathpart
**/

NSMutableDictionary *foldersDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];


for(NSString *path in _folderPaths){

    NSArray *pathParts = [path componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

    for(NSString *pathPart in pathParts){

        if([pathPart length]>0)
        {
            if(![foldersDictionary objectForKey:pathPart])
                [foldersDictionary setObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] forKey:pathPart];
            //Some way to set the new root to reference the Dictionary just created here so it can be easily added to on the next iteration?
        }

    } //end for pathPart in pathParts
} //end for path in _folderPaths

NSLog(@"%@", foldersDictionary);
```

This would log as:

```
documents = {
};
files = {
};
pictures = {
};
```

So I need a way of being able to step deeper into the dictionary with each iteration of the split path. I've done this before in C# on a node view where I could reference a child with a cursor but I'm not finding a way to do this with Objective-C using the pointers.

Comment: To clarify, more information will go in each dictionary otherwise I would use arrays. The child folders would go in a dictionary containing a key/object for each child.

Comment: An alternate structure would be `Array { FolderDictionary, FolderDictionary, ...}` where each `folderDictionary` has keys `name`, `fullPath` and `childFolders` containing an equal Array - this maybe simpler and what I tried to start with.

Comment: But I figured dictionary keys were easier to check for uniqueness against. I'll stop commenting now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close. All you need to do is dynamically change the parent that new dictionaries get added to. You can do this like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *folders = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSString *path in folderPaths) {
    NSMutableArray *folderStack = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:folders];

    for (NSString *component in [path pathComponents]) {
        if ([component isEqualToString:@"/"]) continue;

        NSMutableDictionary *folder = [[folderStack lastObject] objectForKey:component];
        if (folder == nil) {
            folder = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [[folderStack lastObject] setObject:folder forKey:component];
        }
        [folderStack addObject:folder];
    }
}
```

Note that under this method, these arrays would all yield the same result:

```
{"/documents", "/documents/pictures", "/documents/pictures/favorites"}
{"/documents/pictures/favorites", "/documents", "/documents/pictures"}
{"/documents/pictures/favorites"}
```

Comment: Brilliant, referencing the folders dictionary through another array like that is what I had in mind but couldn't get round the mental block! Is splitting on the path like that more efficient than predetermining where it should split? I guess the separatedByString method does the same thing in reality.